# Code sign error in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I got an ios app, whe i trying to build it on device, XCode shows me this error:

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

Any ideas? What is the reason?

Comment: Did you update your key chain with a valid cetificate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just delete all profiles from Key-chain. And the create new profiles in developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Except for the provisioning profile, you need also the private key/certificate exported from the keychain of the creator of the provisioning profile.

Comment: how should i do it? can you explain step by step?

Comment: the creator of the provisioning or another developer using the profile should follow these steps. http://www.utexas.edu/its/help/digital-certificates/812

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action)

You will have to buy a development certificate in order to run your developments on your device.

Of course you can use the simulator free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

To get a valid certificate - you need the user that issued the development certificate for this app to export the certificate files physically from his Mac. This means opening Keychain Access, right clicking the certificate and selecting "Export...". Then when you get this certificate, just open it and it will be added to your chain.